# A function that returns the number of possibilities in an array of integers

Tags: c

The function takes an array of integers, it's lengths, and two integers N1 and N2
it should return an integer describes how many ways you can sum N1 elements of the array to get a summation equals to N2.
How to implement this function?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take the [tour] and read [ask],and [what topics to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  You need to show some effort here.

Comment: Have you tried brute forcing it? It's O(n choose k), but it's also the simplest way to start.

Answer (score 0):

Use recursion. E.g. something vaguely like:

```
int findCount(int *array, int length, int N1, int N2) {
   int count = 0;

   if(N1 == 1) {
       for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
           if(array[i] == N2) {
               count++;
           }
       }
   } else {
       for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
           count += findCount(&array[i+1], length-i-1, N1 - 1, N2 - array[i]);
       }
   }
   return count;
}
```

Note: If the array can't contain zeros or negative numbers you can improve this with an `if(array[i] < N2) count += findCount(&array[i+1], length-i-1, N1 - 1, N2 - array[i]);`.